# Error reading from csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file like this one:

```
time,value,duration,time
2011-02-11 03:00:00,3663,3663,0
2011-02-12 03:00:00,3747,3747,0
2011-02-13 03:00:00,467,467,0
```

This is my code:

> test1 <- read.csv("C:(here goes the path)",header=T,sep="",quote="", row.names = NULL) [,-1]
>   test1[2,2]

The error it says is:

```
Error in `[.default`(test1, 2, 2) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I think the fact that there's a space after the date is messing it up but I don't know how to fix it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try typing "test1" and seeing what it says?  Not sure if it thinks the first field is really two fields

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
test1 <- read.csv(path)[, -1]
```

That command just uses the default parameters for `read.csv`:

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote="\"", dec=".",
         fill = TRUE, comment.char="", ...)
```

So, this is the result that I get:

```
  value duration time.1
1  3663     3663      0
2  3747     3747      0
3   467      467      0
```

which seems to be what you want, right?

Then `test[2, 2]` is equivalent to `test$duration[2]` and equal to 3747.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is really a csv, you need to use `sep=','` which is the default for `read.csv`.  If you use `sep=''` that means you're reading each line as a single value, so there is no second column.

you can also use `str(test1)` to see the structure of your data once you've read it.

```
test1 <- read.csv(path, header=TRUE)
```

That should give you what you want.